# TexLive on Fedora 23

Tags: texlive, linux

I'm trying to use Fedora 23 as OS, but I'm in trouble as my .tex document isn't compiling. 
To be more precise, my document compiles great under my current setup on windows (TexLive2015, full-scheme).
On fedora I installed using the package manager (dnf install texlive-scheme-full)
But it seems to be missing some packages (templatetools, codesection, maybe more).

Is that normal behavior (devs of fedora chose not to include them, or are they considered optional?)

Comment: Welcome, please type `latex --version` into a terminal and hit enter, what ts the first line of the output?

Comment: First line is : `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (Tex Live 2014)`

So it seems like i'm on TexLive 2014, not 2015.

Comment: If you install vanilla from upstream, search for 'vanilla' here to find the main question on this. Although it is for Debian-based distros, it is straightforward to adapt for Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install TeXLive from TUG (http://tug.org/texlive/). It does not interfere with system package manager. And more or less, you can get the same behavior across all platforms.

Just remember to put the `PATH` to texlive binary before everything else. It is possible that there might be some conflicts. For example, an executable within TeXLive has the same name as something total unrelated, instead by the package manager. However, this kind of case is rare can be dealt with easily.

I usually use
`tlmgr path add` to link TeXLive binaries into `/usr/local/bin` etc., and remove any problematic links manually, which is very rare and I haven't need to do this for years.

Answer (score 1):

If you're missing a package and have no idea which rpm to install, try this: `dnf install 'tex(packagename.sty)'`
For codesection, `dnf install 'tex(codesection.sty)'` will install the package texlive-codesection on Fedora 24.

Comment: Thank you for your input on this matter. I did try this on Fedora 23 but wasn'tworking at the time though. I'm glad it is working on fedora 24, will give it a try later.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of normal behaviour, Linux distros tend to break tex-live into smaller chunks to be installed cumulatively.

I suggest that you use the search functionality of your package manager to locate the packages holding the missing style files and than install them.

In rare cases (e.g. when a package was declared obsolete by its author) a package may be still absent. In this cases try a direct install from [CTAN](http://ctan.org).

Comment: That's what I was afraid off. I tried to look for the package providing the missing package, but no correspondance where found. It's not part of the repo. (I tried `dnf provides codesection` for example)

I guess I will have to make a custom install from TUG.

Comment: @Snow Installing a vanilla TeX Live from TUG will indeed be the best choice ;-)